# Dropzone add number of rows to table with the number of files added to dropzone?

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I am using jQuery [Dropzone plugin](http://www.dropzonejs.com/). Under the dropzone I have a table with markup like this

```
<table id="data">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Lets say I have 3 files dropped in the dropzone so I want 3 rows for the input fields to be shown in the table. So for that I have made my js like this

```
Dropzone.options.documentDropzone = {
    init: function () {
        this.on("complete", function (file) {
            if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
                var Length = this.getAcceptedFiles().length; // To get the number of files in the dropzone
                // Loop to add number of rows after adding files to dropzone
                for(i=0; i < Length; i+) {
                            var html = $('<tr><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"name\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"email\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"phone\"></td></tr>');
                            $('table#data').append(html);
                        }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here it is working fine like lets say I have added 3 files for the first time so it is adding 3 rows nicely. Another time lets say I have added 2 files . So in the dropzone I have now 3+2 = 5 files. So it should show 5 files row. But it is showing like this first it showed 3 files then when I added another 2 files then it showed like 3+(3+2) = 8. so can someone tell me how to solve this issue? Any help and suggestions will be really apprecable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `removeAllFiles` method to reset the counter back to 0; assuming that you're using your table for displaying the uploaded files and not the dropzone itself.

```
this.on('complete', function() {
    if (! this.getUploadingFiles().length && ! this.getQueuedFiles().length) {
        var Length = this.getAcceptedFiles().length;
        for (var i = 0; i < Length; i++) {
            var html = $('<tr><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"name\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"email\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"phone\"></td></tr>');
            $('table#data').append(html);
        }
        this.removeAllFiles();
    }
});
```

Edit: Seemed to misinterpret the question, sorry. You could redraw the table when new files are added, as in doing `$('table#data').html(html)` - but that has the downside of clearing what was already in the form, losing any active/focus states etc. From my experience with Dropzone you have to call `removeAllFiles` to stop tracking the older uploads. So if you're fine with just using Dropzone as a means to upload files and not use it for the display then I would go with what I suggested above.

Comment: its not working at all. this.removeAllFiles(); is removing all files I think. Can you recheck it?

Comment: Yeah, I read your question again and I think I got the wrong idea. I have run into this issue myself but decided to just use Dropzone as an uploader, not something to be used for displaying the uploaded files afterwards. I'm not entirely sure if it's possible to keep the uploaded files in the dropzone *and* reset the count of them to zero.